# Serving ArgoCD behind Traefik in Kubernetes

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, devops, traefik, argocd

I would like to run ArgoCD behind Traefik such that I can both access the ArgoCD web ui and interact with the API using the `argocd` command line tool.

- I have deployed ArgoCD into a Kubernetes cluster from [the upstream manifests](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml).
- I have deployed Traefik as in ingress server from the [helm chart](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart). I haven't set any chart values other than the log level.
- I am using the following Ingress resource:

  ```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: argocd

  spec:
    tls:
      - hosts:
        - argocd.internal
        secretName: argocd-certificate
    rules:
      - host: argocd.internal
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: argocd-server
                  port:
                    name: http
  ```
- The secret `argocd-certificate` exists and has a valid certificate and key in `tls.crt` and `tls.key`.

With this in place, I can access ArgoCD at `http://argocd.internal`, but attempts to access it at `https://argocd.internal` fail with:

```
$ curl https://argocd.internal
404 page not found
```

(Note that there is no certificate error; the endpoint is servering the certificate configured in the Ingress resource.)

I'm not sure what's going on here: I haven't bound this to any particular Traefik endpoint, so I would expect it to be available on all endpoints...and when we query the Traefik API, we see:

```
$ curl -sf 'http://localhost:9000/api/http/routers?search=&status=&per_page=6&page=1' |
  jq '.[]|select(.service == "argocd-argocd-server-80")'
{
  "entryPoints": [
    "metrics",
    "web",
    "websecure"
  ],
  "service": "argocd-argocd-server-80",
  "rule": "Host(`argocd.internal`) && PathPrefix(`/`)",
  "status": "enabled",
  "using": [
    "metrics",
    "web",
    "websecure"
  ],
  "name": "argocd-argocd-argocd-internal@kubernetes",
  "provider": "kubernetes"
}
```

Which confirms that the router is available on all endpoints.

What's going on here -- why does this only seem to do the right thing when accessed via `http://` and not via `https://`?

If it helps, the `argocd-server` service looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.96.117.77
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.96.117.77
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things working with a pair of [IngressRoute](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-crd/) resources:

1. One for the `http://` endpoint:

   ```
   apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
   kind: IngressRoute
   metadata:
     name: argocd-http
   spec:
     entryPoints:
       - web
     routes:
     - kind: Rule
       match: Host(`argocd.internal`)
       priority: 10
       middlewares:
         - name: redirect-http-https
       services:
       - kind: Service
         name: argocd-server
         port: http
   ```

   This uses a redirecting middleware to redirect all requests to the `https://` endpoint:

   ```
   apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
   kind: Middleware
   metadata:
     name: redirect-http-https
   spec:
     redirectScheme:
       scheme: https
       permanent: true
   ```

   That means the `services:` portion of the `IngressRoute` is effectively a no-op, but it's required by the schema.
2. And one for the `https://` endpoint:

   ```
   apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
   kind: IngressRoute
   metadata:
     name: argocd-https
   spec:
     entryPoints:
       - websecure
     routes:
     - kind: Rule
       match: Host(`argocd.internal`)
       priority: 10
       services:
       - kind: Service
         name: argocd-server
         port: http
     - kind: Rule
       match: Host(`argocd.internal`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
       priority: 11
       services:
       - kind: Service
         name: argocd-server
         port: http
         scheme: h2c
     tls:
       secretName: argocd-certificate
   ```

   We use the `Content-Type` to differentiate gRPC requests from HTTP requests and use the appropriate protocol scheme for the connection to the backend server.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that your service itself works. Traefik may work correctly, but the service may be unavailable due to failed health checks, mismatched labels or security policies.

Try accessing it with `dig`, `ping`, and `telnet` from within Kubernetes, e.g. with the [`netshoot`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nicolaka/netshoot) container image.

Use the internal service name as a hostname:

`<name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: I have already verified that the service itself works: "With this in place, I can access ArgoCD at `http://argocd.internal`, but..."